# Does detachNewThreadSelector work any different than NSThread performSelectorInBackground or NSThread alloc/init then [thread start]

Tags: objective-c, nsthread

Does `detachNewThreadSelector` work any different than `performSelectorInBackground`?  In my project I use a lot of this:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startImageDownloads:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:dataType]];
```

but would doing this be any different:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startImageDownloads:) toTarget:self withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:dataType]];
```

And also, besides being able to access the thread object with `imgDlThread`, would alloc/init'ing a thread then `start`ing it work any different then the first 2:

```
NSThread *imgDlThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startImageDownloads:) object:[NSNumber numberWithInt:dataType]];
[imgDlThread start];
```

Thanks!

---

**Edit:**

Just realized there's several answers on SO already for the difference (or lack of) between `performSelectorInBackground` and `detachNewThreadSelector`, so I guess my only question is:

*Is allocating and initializing a `NSThread` then calling `[thread start]` any different then the first 2?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between the third method and the first two is memory management. When you allocate a thread, it retains it's `target`, only to be released when the thread is deallocated. The `detatchNewThreadSelector:` and `performSelectorInBackground:` method both autorelease the resulting `NSThread` that is created, meaning that, once the thread finishes execution, the `target` will be released.

In the code that you provided (allocate a thread and start it), you are leaking `imgDlThread`, meaning that `target` will never be released, and in turn will be leaked itself. If you autorelease or even regular release `imgDlThread` after starting it, it will have the exact same effect as `detachNewThreadSelector:`.